# Is "Io" accusative case in "Iuppiter, rex deorum, pulchram Io amabat"?

Tags: declension, names

In *The Adventures of Io*, a story found in *Thirty-eight Latin Stories, Designed to Accompany Wheelock's Latin*, the first sentence of the story is as follows:

> Iuppiter, rēx deōrum, pulchram Iō amābat, sed īram Iūnōnis metuēbat.

> Jupiter, king of the gods, loved beautiful Io but feared Juno's wrath.

What case is *Io* in this sentence, and is it a third declension feminine noun? I would have expected it to be *Ionem*.

Answer (score 14):

A number of Greek names ending in *-ō* have both Latin and Greek style declensions.
For example:

|  | Greek | Latin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nom. | Dīdō | Dīdō |
| acc. | Dīdō | Dīdōnem |
| gen. | Dīdūs | Dīdōnis |
| dat. | Dīdō | Dīdōnī |
| abl. | Dīdō | Dīdōne |

One would indeed expect the typical Latin form *Ionem*, but *Io* is valid as well.
The context is fortunately clear enough so that we can be confident that *Io* is indeed an accusative.
In a more complicated sentence the role can be left quite unclear with the Greek style declension.

Answer (score 13):

For unfamiliar words, it never hurts to check the dictionary. Here is what [Lewis and Short](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DI%3Aentry+group%3D72%3Aentry%3DIo2) have:

> Īō, Iūs, and Īōn , Iōnis, f., = Ἰώ, I.a daughter of Inachus, king of Argos, beloved by Jupiter, and changed, through fear of Juno, into a cow; afterwards worshipped as an Egyptian deity, under the name of Isis. —Form Io, Ov. H. 14, 85; Prop. 2, 28 (3, 24), 17; Ov. M. 1, 588 sq.; Val. Fl. 4, 351 sq.; Hyg. Fab. 145.—Gen. Ius, Nemes. Cyn. 31.—**Acc. Io, Ov. M. 1, 588**; Amm. 2, 19, 29.—Abl. Io, Prop. 2, 13, 19.—Form Ion; dat. Ioni, Plaut. Aul. 3, 6, 20.—Acc. Ionem, Serv. Verg. A. 3, 153.

Annoyingly, the reference is slightly off, but here's the Ovid passage in question (Ov. Met. 1.583-585):

> Inachus unus abest imoque reconditus antro
> fletibus auget aquas natamque miserrimus **Io
>
> luget ut amissam.**

A. S. Kline translates it thus:

> Only Inachus is missing, but hidden in the deepest cave he swells his stream with tears, and in utter misery **laments his lost daughter, Io.**

You'll see that, like *pulchram* in *Thirty-Eight Latin Stories*, here *amissam* is your clue that *Io* is in the accusative case. The context makes that clear.

Comment: I actually looked at this very entry and totally missed that reference, hah!